# How can I reverse the series order of a pyramid chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is an example of pyramid chart in Highcharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pyramid/
Is there any way I can change the top down order

from:

```
Finalized  
Invoice sent  
Requested price list   
Downloads  
Web visits
```

to:

```
Web visits  
Downloads  
Requested price list  
Invoice sent  
Finalized
```

I've tried:

```
plotOptions.funnel.reversed = true/false
yAxis[n].reversed = true/false
xAxis.reversed = true/false
```

none of them works.

Is there any way we can achieve it rather than re-order the `series.data` it self?

(I'll still want the pyramid tip on top)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7wfjv2km/

Comment: If you still want the tip of the pyramid on the top then you'll need to reverse the order of the data. Otherwise do a reversed pyramid.

Comment: Yes, I still want the tip on the top...seems I'll have to reverse the order of my data.

Answer (score 3):

Try set this [plotOptions.pyramid.reversed](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pyramid.reversed) to `false`.